# CardView isn't rendering - ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.cardview.R$color

Tags: android, cardview

I'm trying to implement a CardView into my Android layout and it's giving me a rendering problem.

'The following classes could not be instantiated' - android.support.v7.widget.CardView

**activity_overview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.OverviewActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**app.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Exception Details**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.cardview.R$color
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You could try to move `xmlns:card_view` to under the LinearLayout, where that property should be

Comment: Doing so doesn't fix the issue, even when refreshing. It goes grey and gives me a 'namespace declaration is never used' warning.

Comment: Right, you aren't using it, I was just saying it should be in the root element. Not sure what the solution is, though this seems to be a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826261/trouble-getting-android-support-v7-cardview-library-to-work

Comment: I seemed to have figured it out... apparently I can't use NoActionBar styles with card views, I guess. I changed it back to have an ActionBar and built the project again and now it's fine.

Comment: Hmm. Strange... I wouldn't think that should matter, but then again, I don't remember ever having a CardView without a Toolbar

Comment: I just tried adding the NoActionBar theme back... and now it's working without an action bar too. I guess I'll chalk it up to Android Studio being weird.

Comment: Just had this issue myself. Cleaning the project resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do first add CardView to gradle file and then do Build > Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new file then you will notice a download button against recyclerView and cardView just click on that to get them ready. There is no need to get link from internet from android studio community, as it supports for older versions of android studio.